# Modal dialog: Always return a value using MSCRMs openstddlg() method

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, modal-dialog, return-value

Ok. The tittle sounds like a mouthful to me so let me break it down a bit.

I am using the crm-global.js openStdDlg method to open a modal dialog.

```
openStdDlg("myPage.aspx?" + qs.toString(), null, screen.height, screen.width, true, false, "maximize:yes;minimize:yes");
```

The purpose of this is to open myPage in a new window that can be maximized. myPage is displayed in an iFrame inside of MS CRM and can be hard to work with on smaller screens.

I have 3 different instances where this iFrame is used. In 2 of those instances I can simply include a save button inside of myPage and when myPage is closed I just refresh the original myPage to see the new saved content. The last problem page can't do the save from myPage because there is more information that needs to be included in the save that is part of the parent page.

What I need:

1. I need to be able to return a string from the dialog back to the parent page regardless of how the dialog was closed.
2. The string could potentially be up to 100k char long.

Am i way off in left field? Is there a better way? Can I even pass back a string that large? Thoughts, opinions, rude remarks?

Answer (score 0):

Under the hood that call should be using [window.openDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.openDialog), and as far as I know there isn't any limit on the return value.  However, assuming you are using CRM 2011, and at some point you may want to move to UR 12 (if you haven't already), you should know that `window.openDialog` is not supported by all browsers.

Also, instead of just passing values via the query string to a dialog, there is actually an extra parameter that you can pass an array of arguments to.  I believe that second parameter where you are passing in `null` is the extra arguments.  With the window.openDialog call the optional arguments array is passed in last like this:

```
openDialog("http://example.tld/zzz.xul", "dlg", "", "pizza", 6.98);
```

And then can be accessed like this:

```
var food  = window.arguments[0];
var price = window.arguments[1];
```

Like I mentioned, I don't believe there is a limit, but this is another way that you can get additional information to your dialog.